# ValueError Reading large data set with pd.read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, valueerror

I am working a set of [code exercises](https://courses.springboard.com/courses/enrolled/448797) that use a [Yelp reviews dataset](https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/main). At this point in the exercises I am supposed to read in review.json which has one JSON record per line. I have made a smaller version of the JSON file, with only 100 records, for testing.

I can read the entire test file into a pandas dataframe and examine it.

The complete dataset file, however, has about 6 million lines. The recommendation is to use chunksize and build a json reader. I'm hitting errors, even with my test input.

My code currently looks like this

```
path = 'file://localhost/Users/.../DSC_Intro/'
filename = path + 'yelp_dataset/review_100.json'

# create a reader to read in chunks
review_reader = 
pd.read_json(StringIO(filename), lines=True, chunksize=10)

type(review_reader)
```

The type call returns

```
pandas.io.json.json.JsonReader
```

which looks good.

Then I try

```
for chunk in review_reader:
    print(chunk)
```

as referenced in [pandas user guide](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#line-delimited-json)
and I get an error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding 'false'
```

[image: full error output]

**Update** - it has been suggested that the issue is caused by embedded (quoted) "\n" characters in the data file; that pandas is seeing the JSON records as, not one per line, but multiple lines.

The error message is VERY opaque, if that's the case. Also, with 6 million lines, how should I tell `pd.read_json` to ignore `"\n"` and only look at actual newlines in the data?

**Update**

It's been suggested that if I fix my typo (it was a typo in this post, not a typo in my code) and use a Unix file path instead of a URL (JSON doesn't care: see docs).

When I do this but keep StringIO(), I get a different ValueError.

When I do this but remove StringIO(), the code works.

This seems to be very fragile. :-(

---

**Note** The tutorial has an answer key. I've tried that code. The answer key uses

```
review_reader = 
pd.read_json(filename, lines=True, chunksize=10)
```

which throws the TypeError

```
sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Adding `StringIO()` seems to have solved that.

**Input** Sample JSON record, one per line of the input file.

`{"review_id":"Amo5gZBvCuPc_tZNpHwtsA","user_id":"DzZ7piLBF-WsJxqosfJgtA","business_id":"qx6WhZ42eDKmBchZDax4dQ","stars":5.0,"useful":1,"funny":0,"cool":0,"text":"Our family LOVES the food here. Quick, friendly, delicious, and a great restaurant to take kids to. 5 stars!","date":"2017-03-27 01:14:37"}`

Comment: have you tried pd.from_records?

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240982/valueerror-when-using-pandas-read-json

Comment: Nate - adding encoding="utf8" doesn't change anything but thanks.

Comment: I have cut the input file back to three records; no change to the error. here are no weird or unexpected characters in the input. The file path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your

```
path 'file://localhost/Users/.../DSC_Intro/'
```

is not valid python code. If you try to execute that as such, you will get an invalid syntax error. I assume, then, that this is just showing the value of the path variable. I don't know whether those ellipses are literal or the result of your environment truncating the display of `path`. I'll assume here that your path is a valid file URL for your system as it doesn't seem germane here to consider an incorrect path.

Either way, yes, `read_json` can read json from a file URL as you're specifying there (I learned something there) if you read it in one go:

```
pd.read_json(fname, lines=True)
```

But if you try to create a reader from this, by specifying

```
pd.read_json(fname, lines=True, chunksize=...)
```

then you get

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Secondly, yes, wrapping your file-like argument with StringIO makes this error go away, but it isn't helping for any reason you might think and its use is based on a misreading of the pandas docs you point to.

I'll quote a couple of bits from the `read_json` doc here:

> Signature: pd.read_json(
>       path_or_buf=None, ...
>
> path_or_buf : a valid JSON string or file-like, default: None
>       The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3,
>       gcs, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local
>       file could be `file://localhost/path/to/table.json`

So with read_json, you can either give it an actual string that is valid JSON, or you can give it a file-like object that points to a file that contains JSON.

Notice in the pandas docs that you cite:

```
In [258]: jsonl = '''
   .....:     {"a": 1, "b": 2}
   .....:     {"a": 3, "b": 4}
   .....: '''
   .....:
```

is JSON, not a path. When their example then does:

```
df = pd.read_json(jsonl, lines=True)
```

it is merely parsing the JSON in the string - no files are involved here.
When it then wants to demonstrate reading from a file in chunks, it does

```
# reader is an iterator that returns `chunksize` lines each iteration
In [262]: reader = pd.read_json(StringIO(jsonl), lines=True, chunksize=1)
```

In other words, they are wrapping a JSON string, not a path, by StringIO(). This is just for the purposes of the documented example, so you can see that *if you treated the JSON string as if it were being read from a file* you can read it in chunks. That's what StringIO() does. So when you wrap the string that describes your file URL in StringIO(), I expect that `read_json` is then trying to interpret that string as JSON that's being read from a file and parse it. It understandably falls over because it isn't JSON.

This brings us back to why `read_json` cannot read your file URL in chunks. I don't have an immediate good answer to that. I suspect it lies in the internals of how `read_json` opens file URLs, or what function underlies this. If you were intent upon, or forced to, do this chunking from a file URL then I suspect you'd be looking at controlling the mode in which the file is opened, or perhaps somehow providing explicit guidance to `read_json` how to interpret the bytestream it gets. Libraries such as `urllib2` may be useful here, I'm not sure.

But let's cut to the best fix here. Why are we trying to specify the path as a file URL? Simply specify your path as an OS path, e.g.

```
path = '/path/to/my/data/'
```

and then

```
filename = path + 'yelp_dataset/review_100.json'

# create a reader to read in chunks
review_reader = pd.read_json(filename, lines=True, chunksize=10)
```

And I betcha it works as intended! (It does for me, as it always has).
Caveat: windows doesn't use forward-slash path delimiters, and constructing paths by concatenating strings in the above fashion can be fragile, but usually if you use 'proper' forward-slash delimiters (smile), decent languages internally understand that. It's constructing paths using backslashes that is guaranteed to cause you pain. But just keep an eye on that.

Comment: "0


Firstly, your
path 'file://localhost/Users/.../DSC_Intro/'
is not valid python code."    ===  Yeah, that's a typo. I'm not stupid. My code does run.

Comment: "And I betcha it works as intended!"  My data?  Because no, it doesn't for me. It gives a different ValueError.

Comment: Hi @VickiB, I'm sorry you're obviously frustrated. I've put in a significant amount of unpaid effort to try to help you here. Your issue does fundamentally seem to come from you specifying the file as a URL rather than a path, as supported by this reply https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27135#issuecomment-507036118 to my pandas issue, which means you're receiving binary data, which in turn causes a problem for readlines. To reiterate, do use a path, not URL, don't use StringIO anywhere, and it should work.