# Read JSON file with multiple objects inside Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, jsonlines

I am trying to read a json file in Python and convert it into a dataframe. The problem is that my json file has several json objects inside. The structure of my json is like this:

```
{"Temp":"2,3", "OutsideTemp" : "3,4",...}
{"Temp":"3,2", "OutsideTemp" : "4,4",...}
{"Temp":"2,8", "OutsideTemp" : "3,7",...}
...
```

I've tried using json lines and pandas.read_json but only got errors. (I'm noob at python as you can see, help me!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('data.txt', lines=True)
df = df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace(',','.')).astype(float)
print(df.info())
df
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Temp           3 non-null float64
OutsideTemp    3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes
None
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You have a [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format text file, so set `lines=True`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('data.txt', lines=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Temp OutsideTemp
0  2,3         3,4
1  3,2         4,4
2  2,8         3,7
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas-read-json):

> lines bool, default False
> Read the file as a json object per line.

Note that you have to change `data.txt` in the snippet above to your actual file name.

Comment: I used your code and received the following error: ValueError: unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)

Comment: @heyou Perhaps this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240982/valueerror-when-using-pandas-read-json