# Read truncated json file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file that is truncated. I have been looking for a way to read it into a pandas dataframe, but not been successfull. Several post refers to the [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json).

I've tried below approach;

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("C:/Users/user1/Documents/history_truncated.json")
df.head()

### Results in ###
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)
```

A similar issue is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240982/valueerror-when-using-pandas-read-json) where the solution was to use an absolute path. In my case that did not work. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

## Edit adding last few lines to question

```
"departurePlatformName":null,"departureBoardingActivity":0,"departureBoardingActivitySpecified":true,"departureStopAssignment":null,
"departureOperatorRefs":null,"aimedHeadwayInterval":null,"expectedHeadwayInterval":null,"distanceFromStop":null,"numberOfStopsAway":null,"extensions":null},{"stopPointRef":{"value":"SE:276:Quay:9022012013003041"},"visitNumber":"1","order":"7","stopPointName":null,"item":false,"itemElementName":0,"predictionInaccurateSpecified":false,"occupancySpecified":false,"timingPointSpecified":false,"boardingStretch":false,"requestStop":false,"originDisplay":null,"destinationDisplay":null,"callNote":null,"facilityConditionElement":null,"facilityChangeElement":null,"situationRef":null,"aimedArrivalTime":"2022-08-30T09:33:00+02:00","aimedArrivalTimeSpecified":true,"expectedArrivalTime":"2022-08-30T09:33:00+02:00","expectedArrivalTimeSpecified":true,"expectedArrivalPredictionQuality":null,"arrivalStatus":0,"arrivalStatusSpecified":true,"arrivalProximityText":null,"arrivalPlatformName":null,"arrivalBoardingActivity":0,"arrivalBoardingActivitySpecified":true,"arrivalStopAssignment":null,"arrivalOperatorRefs":null,"aimedDepartureTimeSpecified":false,"expectedDepartureTimeSpecified":false,"provisionalExpectedDepartureTimeSpecified":false,"earliestExpectedDepartureTimeSpecified":false,"expectedDeparturePredictionQuality":null,"aimedLatestPassengerAccessTimeSpecified":false,"expectedLatestPassengerAccessTimeSpecified":false,"departureStatus":0,"departureStatusSpecified":true,"departureProximityText":null,"departurePlatformName":null,"departureBoardingActivity":0,
"departureBoardingActivitySpecified":true,
"departureStopAssignment":null,
"departureOperatorRefs":null,"aimedHeadwayInterval":null,
"expectedHeadwayInterval":null,"distanceFromStop":null,
"numberOfStopsAway":null,"extensions":null}],"isCompleteStopSequence":true,
"extensions":null}
}]
}]]}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in your JSON file?

Comment: If the file has been truncated then it's very likely that its contents do not represent valid JSON. Add the last few lines from the file to your question

Comment: I've received it via email. I tried parsing it [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) but it did raise some Errors. I thought it was due to the truncated format. Is there a way I can share the file?

Comment: I made an edit where I added the last few lines @Cobra

Comment: @OLGJ The end of the JSON looks as though it *may* be valid. You now need to explain what makes you think the JSON data are truncated. What errors were shown when you tried the online JSON validator?

Comment: As per the email I received from my client/company contact it supposedly is so. Four errors, 2 of them being `Error: Expecting comma or ], not }` and 2 of them being `Error: Expecting comma or }, not ]`.

Comment: I did addressed the errors and swapped ] to } and vice versa. It is able to load now, but the data is returned in a odd format, where the items I'd like to access is stored in a nested dictionary as a value in one of the rows. But that is perchance a different issue/topic